# Can this batch file damage/prevent Windows 10 from booting?

Tags: windows, batch-file, bsod

Is there anything in the below `.bat` script that could delete/corrupt any Windows 10 system files and prevent them from starting, causing a boot loop? After rebooting, following the execution of the `.bat`, Windows won't start and displays `Critical Service Failed`:

- I ran the `.bat` as Admin, both from the flash drive, then from `C:`, and a Cmd terminal opened with filenames that are **not** on the flash drive being processed, which was fishy:

  ```bat
  takeown /f "H:\PVR" /r
  icacls "H:\PVR" /reset /t

  for /r "H:\PVR" %%i in (*.ts *.tsv) do move "%%i" "H:\PVR"

  cd /d "H:\PVR"
  ren *.tsv *.ts

  for /f "delims=" %%d in ('dir /ad /b') do @rd /q /s "%%d"
  setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

  for %%a in (*.ts *.tsv) do (
    set name=%%~Na
    set num=00!random!
    set newName=!!name:~-17!
    ren "%%a" "!newName!%%~Xa"
  )
  ```

  I put together this script, combining several commands found here and other places, in order to process `.ts` recordings on a flash drive from my DVBT-T2 receiver, with the idea being to:

  1. Take permission of `H:\PVR` and all its contents
  2. Move `.tsv` recordings out of subfolders, deleting the subfolders
  3. Rename `.tsv` extensions to `.ts`
  4. Remove first 17 characters from filenames, as I don't like the prefix format of the receiver

How do I troubleshoot this?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123272/discussion-on-question-by-slade-can-this-batch-file-damage-prevent-windows-10-fr).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *...Then a CMD window opened and I saw filenames which are not in my flash drive being processed which was fishy...*

1. Go to `H:`:

   ```bat
   cd /d H:\
   ```
2. If **`cd /d H:\`** returns non-`0`, the operator will execute the next command after `||`, making the batch script go to the end of the file [`goto :eOf`], ending the execution without actions in other folders/files:

   ```bat
   cd /d H:\ || goto :eOf
   ```
3. If last command returned successfully, it will execute `takeown` and `icacls` commands within `H:`:

   ```bat
   %__AppDir__%takeown.exe /f H:\PVR\. /r
   %__AppDir__%icacls.exe H:\PVR\. /reset /t
   ```

   For *`takeown`* and *`icals`* commands, use a pause to see the screen:

   ```bat
   :: # One space before  ^  and no space and/or another character after  ^  :
      %__AppDir__%takeown.exe /f .\PVR\. /r | <nul ^
      %__AppDir__%Findstr.exe "(or.*):" & %__AppDir__%timeout.exe /t -1

      %__AppDir__%icacls.exe .\PVR\. /reset /t |  <nul ^
      %__AppDir__%Find.exe "files; Fai" & %__AppDir__%timeout.exe /t -1
   ```

   To remove timeout:

   ```bat
   %__AppDir__%takeown.exe /f .\PVR\. /r && %__AppDir__%icacls.exe .\PVR\. /reset /t
   ```
4. List [`Sort`] folder/tree in reverse mode [`/r`] to get the last sub-folder/dir in the directory tree and, where possible, move files and remove the current directory:

   ```bat
   for /f usebacktokens^=* %i in (`dir /b /s /ad-h H:\PVR\.^|%__AppDir__%Sort.exe /r
   ```

   ```bat
   $ Dir /b /s /ad-h D:\PVR|%__AppDir__%Sort.exe /r

     H:\PVR\tmp
     H:\PVR\Dir 003\tmp
     H:\PVR\Dir 003
     H:\PVR\Dir 002\tmp
     H:\PVR\Dir 002
     H:\PVR\Dir 001\tmp
     H:\PVR\Dir 001
     H:\PVR\Dir 000\tmp
     H:\PVR\Dir 000
   ```
5. For each folder in loop, move `*.ts?` files, applying to `*.ts` and `*.tsv` files within `\PVR\.`; if no error occurs [file/folder in use, etc.], remove folder, else rename files: (`.\PVR\*.tsv` → `*.ts`)

   ```bat
   move "%%~fi\*.ts?" H:\PVR\ && rd "%%~fi" && rename H:\PVR\*.tsv *.ts

   move "%%~fi\*.ts?" H:\PVR\ if return 0 do:
     rd "%%~fi" &&  if return 0 do:
       rename H:\PVR\*.tsv *.ts
   ```

   Where I assume there are no other *`*.ts`* files in folders and you need remove this folder [`@rd /q /s "%%d"`]; if not the case, replace last lines with:

   ```bat
   for /f usebacktokens^=* %%i in (`Dir /b /s /ad-h H:\PVR^|%__AppDir__%Sort.exe /r
     `)do ( move "%%~fi\*.tsv" D:\PVR\. && move "%%~fi\*.ts" H:\PVR\.
     ) && ( rmDir /s /q "%%~fi" && rename D:\PVR\*.tsv *.ts )
   ```
6. To use a newly defined variable on the same line and at run time to obtain the value, invoke `cmd /v /c !Newly defined variable!`; this is what is being done to rename files by limiting the length of the name to a maximum of 17 characters in **`!_new:~-17!`** (same as last 17 characters)

   ```bat
   set "_new=%%~ni" && in the same line use: cmd.exe /v:on /c rename "%%~fi" "!_new:~-17!%%~xi"
   ```

   - My personal preference is to use `where` for the ease of returning the full path of the files; unlike `dir /b`, it does not display the lower case strings:

     ```bat
     for /f useback^tokens^=* %%i in (`2^>nul %__AppDir__%where.exe "H:\PVR":"*.ts*"
     `)do set "_new=%%~ni" && cmd.exe /v:on /c rename "%%~fi" "!_new:~-17!%%~xi"
     ```
   - I added `useback` (abbreviated to **`usebackq`**) to avoid unexpected behavior if any special characters may be present in the file name/path, even though it was not posted strings/layout make up the file names

---

---

To deal with moving/renaming files:

```bat
@echo off

cd /d H:\.. || goto :eof
setlocal Enabledelayedexpansion

%__AppDir__%takeown.exe /f .\PVR\. /r | <nul ^
  %__AppDir__%Findstr.exe "(or.*):" & %__AppDir__%timeout.exe /t -1

%__AppDir__%icacls.exe .\PVR\. /reset /t |  <nul ^
  %__AppDir__%Find.exe "files;.Fa" & %__AppDir__%timeout.exe /t -01

for /f usebacktokens^=* %%i in (`Dir /b /s /ad-h H:\PVR^|%__AppDir__%Sort.exe /r
  `)do move "%%~fi\*.ts?" H:\PVR\ && rd "%%~fi" && rename H:\PVR\*.tsv *.ts

for /f useback^tokens^=* %%i in (`2^>nul %__AppDir__%where.exe "H:\PVR":"*.ts*"
  `)do set "_new=%%~ni" && cmd.exe /v:on /c rename "%%~fi" "!_new:~-17!%%~xi"

endlocal & %__AppDir__%timeout.exe /t -1 | echo\iS dONE! & goto :eof || exit /b
```

- Output:

  ```bat
    H:\PVR\tmp\F0HZCERYIEYKY--U0O69.ts
    H:\PVR\tmp\4-W5N0-6QDOWYAS-YYW-.ts
    H:\PVR\tmp\-PD2MDWHFIL5VP0DWCN8.tsv
    H:\PVR\tmp\SZAAC--91GQCH7OD9-0P.tsv
      4 file(s) moved.

  Removed: "H:\PVR\tmpi" Moved: tmp\*.ts?

    H:\PVR\Dir 000\tmp\I9aKTe38uRqcmkh2B7GF.ts
    H:\PVR\Dir 000\tmp\BBPcfN7R9jg1ESsgHsnA.ts
    H:\PVR\Dir 000\tmp\FRAEKeG1HnMZTmBpY6CB.tsv
    H:\PVR\Dir 000\tmp\EHuI3OiwSRGZWg7fsxsT.tsv
      4 file(s) moved.

  Removed: "H:\PVR\Dir 000\tmpi" Moved: tmp\*.ts?

    H:\PVR\Dir 001\tmp\HZH4jcvj2GvQzf7og5h3.ts
    H:\PVR\Dir 001\tmp\EHRR1jKp3owr4lIsZZre.ts
    H:\PVR\Dir 001\tmp\1c0sB7o881uCGiYZUnvh.tsv
    H:\PVR\Dir 001\tmp\PnDUHnrCAGeUB3RRnwF5.tsv
      4 file(s) moved.

  Removed: "H:\PVR\Dir 001\tmpi" Moved: tmp\*.ts?

    H:\PVR\Dir 002\tmp\nqRuQhA9WrXvPk7i2ywt.ts
    H:\PVR\Dir 002\tmp\7b4hGoKaA9HxiSXtbpAT.ts
    H:\PVR\Dir 002\tmp\Y6PbfweT6aSgDiDDCVdU.tsv
    H:\PVR\Dir 002\tmp\qvnIDtkY7uKtfcgStHzq.tsv
      4 file(s) moved.

  Removed: "H:\PVR\Dir 002\tmpi" Moved: tmp\*.ts?

    H:\PVR\Dir 003\tmp\wnAVPzdos4RWjrJTt9cr.ts
    H:\PVR\Dir 003\tmp\EXDlfbAqCyfB23l7ZZHz.ts
    H:\PVR\Dir 003\tmp\lgAduikvz4vlF1PWA892.tsv
    H:\PVR\Dir 003\tmp\JcBmygrENpU4kEOOIFqP.tsv
      4 file(s) moved.

  Removed: "H:\PVR\Dir 003\tmpi" Moved: tmp\*.ts?

    H:\PVR\Dir 000\SvRxVxF6ZDr7a8R5F9z5.ts
    H:\PVR\Dir 000\1tZDpWwpCVNqrxwr993C.ts
    H:\PVR\Dir 000\BXKSG8q0vo3bXCgaNr7K.tsv
    H:\PVR\Dir 000\qtPe80WQRRrms1Iga1i3.tsv
      4 file(s) moved.

  Removed: "H:\PVR\Dir 000i" Moved: Dir 000\*.ts?

    H:\PVR\Dir 001\NXGbTP1AlPxJGRPWaUJx.ts
    H:\PVR\Dir 001\Q2Eq97QpY7XQ7reWjUMi.ts
    H:\PVR\Dir 001\UEAkSw76WV9j0494Lpvv.tsv
    H:\PVR\Dir 001\IFBoWCY483HQE94fpCHU.tsv
      4 file(s) moved.

  Removed: "H:\PVR\Dir 001i" Moved: Dir 001\*.ts?

    H:\PVR\Dir 002\4nSfuQtqqOF6rPrs9TKb.ts
    H:\PVR\Dir 002\iNEIDXVdvKkN7abkFZJj.ts
    H:\PVR\Dir 002\ygWGThdkefADZpMKWq30.tsv
    H:\PVR\Dir 002\GLLcbLS8QZngJSDfM9k4.tsv
      4 file(s) moved.

  Removed: "H:\PVR\Dir 002i" Moved: Dir 002\*.ts?

    H:\PVR\Dir 003\i1wW84pUm5TEGCWTueFw.ts
    H:\PVR\Dir 003\N7s3dLHI5QzdrkGZJJju.ts
    H:\PVR\Dir 003\T1lQu7bcvmQepdh8iVzp.tsv
    H:\PVR\Dir 003\izNYHYHzFf4moJZPcOJv.tsv
      4 file(s) moved.

  Removed: "H:\PVR\Dir 003i" Moved: Dir 003\*.ts?
  ```

```bat
$ where /r .\PVR *.*

  H:\PVR\YHYHzFf4moJZPcOJv.ts
  H:\PVR\I51RPV68L-6MKLEHV.ts
  H:\PVR\-IE2WZ5MGZ0NOYAC8.ts
  H:\PVR\MYVS0GIQKLSZ99-PI.ts
  H:\PVR\1WMI4-W-0DH2C9V9O.ts
  H:\PVR\ZCERYIEYKY--U0O69.ts
  H:\PVR\5N0-6QDOWYAS-YYW-.ts
  H:\PVR\2MDWHFIL5VP0DWCN8.ts
  H:\PVR\AC--91GQCH7OD9-0P.ts
  H:\PVR\KTe38uRqcmkh2B7GF.ts
  H:\PVR\cfN7R9jg1ESsgHsnA.ts
  H:\PVR\EKeG1HnMZTmBpY6CB.ts
  H:\PVR\I3OiwSRGZWg7fsxsT.ts
  H:\PVR\4jcvj2GvQzf7og5h3.ts
  H:\PVR\R1jKp3owr4lIsZZre.ts
  H:\PVR\sB7o881uCGiYZUnvh.ts
  H:\PVR\UHnrCAGeUB3RRnwF5.ts
  H:\PVR\uQhA9WrXvPk7i2ywt.ts
  H:\PVR\hGoKaA9HxiSXtbpAT.ts
  H:\PVR\bfweT6aSgDiDDCVdU.ts
  H:\PVR\IDtkY7uKtfcgStHzq.ts
  H:\PVR\VPzdos4RWjrJTt9cr.ts
  H:\PVR\lfbAqCyfB23l7ZZHz.ts
  H:\PVR\duikvz4vlF1PWA892.ts
  H:\PVR\mygrENpU4kEOOIFqP.ts
  H:\PVR\xVxF6ZDr7a8R5F9z5.ts
  H:\PVR\DpWwpCVNqrxwr993C.ts
  H:\PVR\SG8q0vo3bXCgaNr7K.ts
  H:\PVR\e80WQRRrms1Iga1i3.ts
  H:\PVR\bTP1AlPxJGRPWaUJx.ts
  H:\PVR\q97QpY7XQ7reWjUMi.ts
  H:\PVR\kSw76WV9j0494Lpvv.ts
  H:\PVR\oWCY483HQE94fpCHU.ts
  H:\PVR\fuQtqqOF6rPrs9TKb.ts
  H:\PVR\IDXVdvKkN7abkFZJj.ts
  H:\PVR\GThdkefADZpMKWq30.ts
  H:\PVR\cbLS8QZngJSDfM9k4.ts
  H:\PVR\W84pUm5TEGCWTueFw.ts
  H:\PVR\3dLHI5QzdrkGZJJju.ts
  H:\PVR\Qu7bcvmQepdh8iVzp.ts
    is done!
```

---

To reproduce my test scenario for the above code, get a free flash drive, and replace the corresponding drive letter:

```bat
@echo off

cd /d H:\.. || goto :eof
setlocal Enabledelayedexpansion

  :: #  create folder for sample/test...

    :: #  H:\
    :: #  \---PVR
    :: #    +---tmp
    :: #    +---Dir 000
    :: #    |  \---tmp
    :: #    +---Dir 001
    :: #    |  \---tmp
    :: #    +---Dir 002
    :: #    |  \---tmp
    :: #    \---Dir 003
    :: #    |  \---tmp

:: # make folders ".\PVR\tmp\." and ".\PVR\Dir 000\tmp\."
  mkdir ".\PVR\tmp\."   ".\PVR\Dir 000\tmp\."

:: # make folders ".\PVR\Dir 001\tmp\." and ".\PVR\Dir 002\tmp\." and ".\PVR\Dir 003\tmp\."
  mkdir ".\PVR\Dir 001\tmp\."   ".\PVR\Dir 002\tmp\."   ".\PVR\Dir 003\tmp\."

  :: # Dir /b /s /ad-h /o-d outputs:
  :: # H:\PVR
  :: # H:\PVR\tmp
  :: # H:\PVR\Dir 000
  :: # H:\PVR\Dir 001
  :: # H:\PVR\Dir 002
  :: # H:\PVR\Dir 003
  :: # H:\PVR\Dir 000\tmp
  :: # H:\PVR\Dir 001\tmp
  :: # H:\PVR\Dir 002\tmp
  :: # H:\PVR\Dir 003\tmp

:: # Show folder the tree/dir created above and list folders
  %__AppDir__%tree.com /a /f .
  %__AppDir__%Timeout.exe  -1 | dir /b /s /ad-h /o-d

echo\UD5I51RPV68L-6MKLEHV.ts >".\PVR\UD5I51RPV68L-6MKLEHV.ts"
echo\5F5-IE2WZ5MGZ0NOYAC8.ts >".\PVR\5F5-IE2WZ5MGZ0NOYAC8.ts"
echo\UY6MYVS0GIQKLSZ99-PI.tsv >".\PVR\UY6MYVS0GIQKLSZ99-PI.tsv"
echo\QA01WMI4-W-0DH2C9V9O.tsv >".\PVR\QA01WMI4-W-0DH2C9V9O.tsv"

echo\F0HZCERYIEYKY--U0O69.ts >".\PVR\tmp\F0HZCERYIEYKY--U0O69.ts"
echo\4-W5N0-6QDOWYAS-YYW-.ts >".\PVR\tmp\4-W5N0-6QDOWYAS-YYW-.ts"
echo\-PD2MDWHFIL5VP0DWCN8.tsv >".\PVR\tmp\-PD2MDWHFIL5VP0DWCN8.tsv"
echo\SZAAC--91GQCH7OD9-0P.tsv >".\PVR\tmp\SZAAC--91GQCH7OD9-0P.tsv"

echo\SvRxVxF6ZDr7a8R5F9z5.ts >".\PVR\Dir 000\SvRxVxF6ZDr7a8R5F9z5.ts"
echo\1tZDpWwpCVNqrxwr993C.ts >".\PVR\Dir 000\1tZDpWwpCVNqrxwr993C.ts"
echo\BXKSG8q0vo3bXCgaNr7K.tsv >".\PVR\Dir 000\BXKSG8q0vo3bXCgaNr7K.tsv"
echo\qtPe80WQRRrms1Iga1i3.tsv >".\PVR\Dir 000\qtPe80WQRRrms1Iga1i3.tsv"

echo\I9aKTe38uRqcmkh2B7GF.ts >".\PVR\Dir 000\tmp\I9aKTe38uRqcmkh2B7GF.ts"
echo\BBPcfN7R9jg1ESsgHsnA.ts >".\PVR\Dir 000\tmp\BBPcfN7R9jg1ESsgHsnA.ts"
echo\FRAEKeG1HnMZTmBpY6CB.tsv >".\PVR\Dir 000\tmp\FRAEKeG1HnMZTmBpY6CB.tsv"
echo\EHuI3OiwSRGZWg7fsxsT.tsv >".\PVR\Dir 000\tmp\EHuI3OiwSRGZWg7fsxsT.tsv"

echo\NXGbTP1AlPxJGRPWaUJx.ts >".\PVR\Dir 001\NXGbTP1AlPxJGRPWaUJx.ts"
echo\Q2Eq97QpY7XQ7reWjUMi.ts >".\PVR\Dir 001\Q2Eq97QpY7XQ7reWjUMi.ts"
echo\UEAkSw76WV9j0494Lpvv.tsv >".\PVR\Dir 001\UEAkSw76WV9j0494Lpvv.tsv"
echo\IFBoWCY483HQE94fpCHU.tsv >".\PVR\Dir 001\IFBoWCY483HQE94fpCHU.tsv"

echo\HZH4jcvj2GvQzf7og5h3.ts >".\PVR\Dir 001\tmp\HZH4jcvj2GvQzf7og5h3.ts"
echo\EHRR1jKp3owr4lIsZZre.ts >".\PVR\Dir 001\tmp\EHRR1jKp3owr4lIsZZre.ts"
echo\1c0sB7o881uCGiYZUnvh.ts >".\PVR\Dir 001\tmp\1c0sB7o881uCGiYZUnvh.tsv"
echo\PnDUHnrCAGeUB3RRnwF5.tsv >".\PVR\Dir 001\tmp\PnDUHnrCAGeUB3RRnwF5.tsv"

echo\4nSfuQtqqOF6rPrs9TKb.tv >".\PVR\Dir 002\4nSfuQtqqOF6rPrs9TKb.ts"
echo\iNEIDXVdvKkN7abkFZJj.tv >".\PVR\Dir 002\iNEIDXVdvKkN7abkFZJj.ts"
echo\ygWGThdkefADZpMKWq30.tsv >".\PVR\Dir 002\ygWGThdkefADZpMKWq30.tsv"
echo\GLLcbLS8QZngJSDfM9k4.tsv >".\PVR\Dir 002\GLLcbLS8QZngJSDfM9k4.tsv"

echo\nqRuQhA9WrXvPk7i2ywt.ts >".\PVR\Dir 002\tmp\nqRuQhA9WrXvPk7i2ywt.ts"
echo\7b4hGoKaA9HxiSXtbpAT.ts >".\PVR\Dir 002\tmp\7b4hGoKaA9HxiSXtbpAT.ts"
echo\Y6PbfweT6aSgDiDDCVdU.tsv >".\PVR\Dir 002\tmp\Y6PbfweT6aSgDiDDCVdU.tsv"
echo\qvnIDtkY7uKtfcgStHzq.tsv >".\PVR\Dir 002\tmp\qvnIDtkY7uKtfcgStHzq.tsv"

echo\i1wW84pUm5TEGCWTueFw.ts >".\PVR\Dir 003\i1wW84pUm5TEGCWTueFw.ts"
echo\N7s3dLHI5QzdrkGZJJju.ts >".\PVR\Dir 003\N7s3dLHI5QzdrkGZJJju.ts"
echo\T1lQu7bcvmQepdh8iVzp.tsv >".\PVR\Dir 003\T1lQu7bcvmQepdh8iVzp.tsv"
echo\izNYHYHzFf4moJZPcOJv.tsv >".\PVR\Dir 003\izNYHYHzFf4moJZPcOJv.tsv"

echo\wnAVPzdos4RWjrJTt9cr.ts >".\PVR\Dir 003\tmp\wnAVPzdos4RWjrJTt9cr.ts"
echo\EXDlfbAqCyfB23l7ZZHz.ts >".\PVR\Dir 003\tmp\EXDlfbAqCyfB23l7ZZHz.ts"
echo\lgAduikvz4vlF1PWA892.tsv >".\PVR\Dir 003\tmp\lgAduikvz4vlF1PWA892.tsv"
echo\JcBmygrENpU4kEOOIFqP.tsv >".\PVR\Dir 003\tmp\JcBmygrENpU4kEOOIFqP.tsv"

:: # put a copy from outputs [tree]+[dir] into the clipboard and exit
  (dir /b /s /ad-h /o-d & %__AppDir__%tree.com /a /f . ) | %__AppDir__%clip.exe

endlocal & goto :eof
```

---

#### Additional Resources:

- [`Where`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/where)
- [`For /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)
- [`For /F`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/for)
- [`Dir /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html)
- [`Tree /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/tree.html)
- [`Findstr`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/findstr)
- [`Move /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/move.html)
- [Redirection](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php)

  - `|`, `<`, `>`, `2>`, etc.
- Undocumented variables :

  - [`%__AppDir__%`](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6137)  | [`%__CD__%`](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6137)
  - [Environment](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html)
- [How does the Windows Command Interpreter [`cmd.exe`] Parse Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4094699/6819406)

Comment: That's all very clever but it's quite a bit more complex than what he had..  and it's better if it's something that he understands more easily.. Perhaps you can give some explanations of why you added e.g. usebackq, and comspec and so on.. i'm sure you have good reasons.. but it'd help if you stated those reasons. But if you don't have time that's understandable.. I suppose your answer helps him out anyhow even if it's not as easy to understand as what he had and is without explanation of how it gets from what the had to what you have.

Comment: @barlop I'm doing this now... and add some more script to create/scenery for test... thank for comment...

Comment: @It Wasn't Me  Wow, that's impressive. I appreciate A LOT the fact you went into the trouble of typing all this, not only answering, but in true "Teach a man how to fish" fashion, explaining stuff and even how to create a testing environment. I am still trying to recover from my mistake (setting up Windows / reinstalling stuff...) but I will give it a go, as soon as I can. Thanks a lot for all this!

Comment: @Slade Well, so sorry for your Windows' event ... and I really like to write scripts ... and, thank you comments ... good luck with your computer...

Comment: @Slade So sorry my limited English, but is some wrong with it, put the blame in google translator, ok?

Comment: @It Wasn't Me That's not a problem at all, I do understand your english, if anything it's the code that gives me a bit of a hard time, but hopefully I'll get better, eventually. Cheers! :)