# Delete duplicate files based on file size

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, batch, batch-file

I have a bunch of files in a directory (with sub directories) which start with same name appended with different letters. I would like to keep the version with the largest file size.

Files look like

```bat
AAA_CAD.cvs     //   Size: 01MB
AAA_PDA.cvs     //   Size: 05MB
AAA_DEF3.cvs    //   Size: 02MB
AAA_DAG.cvs     //   Size: 03MB
...
BBB_CAD.cvs     //   Size: 10MB
BBB_PDA.cvs     //   Size: 05MB
BBB_DEF3.cvs    //   Size: 02MB
BBB_DAG.cvs     //   Size: 13MB
```

I would like to keep only the largest size version:

```bat
AAA_PDA.cvs     //   Size: 05MB
BBB_DAG.cvs     //   Size: 13MB
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: This is what `Get-ChildItem, Remove-Item` cmdlets (see the Powershell help files) are for and sort by size and delete the rest. this is a very common thing to do and not a specific thing for PowerShell. You can do this via Windows batch files (.bat/.cmd) or virtually any scripting language. There are tons of examples all over the web and show in Youtube videos. You need to show what you have tried. SuperUser is not a script writing service. We will help you fix the code you are having issues with.

Comment: [1] sort the files by size - largest last. [2] group by the file prefix. [3] take the last item from each group.

Comment: Are always the first 4 letters the same for 1 file group or does that vary? Does the underscore "_" set the limit of the part of the name that is the same for a file group?

Answer (score 2):

There's a program that can help you with that.

[DupeGuru](https://dupeguru.voltaicideas.net/) is a free and open source software to find duplicate files. You can use that to search duplicates, *and select what to conserve depending on file size, date, etc*.

Answer (score 2):

In PowerShell you can do this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'X:\TheDirectory' -Filter '*.cvs' -File -Recurse |
    # group the files on the part of the name before the first underscore
    Group-Object @{expression = {($_.Name -split '_')[0]}} | ForEach-Object {
    # sort the items in the group on Length; skip the last one (the largest file)
    $_.Group | Sort-Object Length | Select-Object -SkipLast 1 | 
        # and remove the rest
        ForEach-Object { $_ | Remove-Item -WhatIf }
}
```

Remove the `-WhatIf` safety switch if you are satisfied the info in the console shows the correct files would be deleted.

Comment: I tried the above with the below command . powershell.exe  -executionpolicy bypass -noexit "& 'test.ps1'" and it didnt seem to delete anything

Comment: @Anna, see the last line in my answer. Remove the `-WhatIf` switch and then the files **will** be deleted. This is a safety option so you can first see if the code _would_ delete the correct files.

Comment: This code just removes everything except the one the one with the largest size, i wanted it keep one for all the same pattern. From the above example i want to keep both AAA_PDA and BBB_DAG cvs

Comment: @Anna That's because you specifically asked for that: _"I would like to keep the version with the largest file size"_

Answer (score 0):

```bat
@echo off

cd/d "X:\Root Dir"||goto :eof 
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion 

for /f tokens^=* %%G in ('where /r .\ *_*.cvs /t'
    )do set "_n=%%~nG" & call %:^) "!_n!" "_!_n:*_=!"

%:^)
if not "%~1" == "" (set "_file=%~1" && (for /f skip^=1^tokens^=1^,4* %%I in (
    'where /r .\ !_file:%~2^=!_*.cvs /t^|sort /r')do del /q /f /a: "%%K") & exit /b 
    )else endlocal && goto :eOf
```

---

I understand that this type of action can lead to an irreversible error when applying an attempt without the proper backups first.

I also understand that without much knowledge/intimacy with the behavior of the tool used, some bad (unexpected) result may result in just trying such a task.

---

Considering this, below is a way to create a scenario for testing without exposing the real environment to risks of irreversible loss, and safe evaluation of the results before applying it to the real files/folders involved.

- The scope is summarized in:

  - Create a folder structure/tree
  - Create files in the tree and with different sizes
  - Check the results of the commands with the pre-set files as larger
  - Apply the commands to delete the files keeping the largest files
  - Check the results and if other files (unique) were kept

It intends to be something similar to what was elaborated/suggested
along the lines of this [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1643583/969781)

---

## Create a folder structure/tree

```bat
for %%i in (1,2,3,4)do for %%I in (1,2,3,4
    )do 2>nul md "%~dp0\Root Dir\Dir 00%%i\Sub Dir 00%%I"
```

The tree of created folders results in:

```bat
> Tree /A 
Folder PATH listing
Volume serial number is 9A8E-862E
X:.
\---Root Dir
    +---Dir 001
    |   +---Sub Dir 001
    |   +---Sub Dir 002
    |   +---Sub Dir 003
    |   \---Sub Dir 004
    +---Dir 002
    |   +---Sub Dir 001
    |   +---Sub Dir 002
    |   +---Sub Dir 003
    |   \---Sub Dir 004
    +---Dir 003
    |   +---Sub Dir 001
    |   +---Sub Dir 002
    |   +---Sub Dir 003
    |   \---Sub Dir 004
    \---Dir 004
        +---Sub Dir 001
        +---Sub Dir 002
        +---Sub Dir 003
        \---Sub Dir 004
```

---

## Create files in the tree and with different sizes

```bat
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\AAA_ABC.cvs" 11326000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\BBB_ABC.cvs"  9506000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\CCC_ABC.cvs" 10690000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\DDD_ABC.cvs" 14995000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\EEE_ABC.cvs"  7431000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\A00_ABC.cvs"  7131000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 001\AAA_AAC.cvs" 11964000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 001\BBB_APD.cvs"  3307000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 001\CCC_AED.cvs"  3878000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 001\DDD_AAD.cvs" 13346000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 001\EEE_ART.cvs" 11001000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 001\B00_ART.cvs" 14115000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 002\AAA_ADC.cvs"  9417000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 002\BBB_AAD.cvs"  6965000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 002\CCC_ADF.cvs"  6282000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 002\DDD_AGD.cvs" 13628000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 002\EEE_AXT.cvs"  6987000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 002\C00_AXT.cvs" 12587000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 003\AAA_ADA.cvs" 10995000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 003\BBB_AAP.cvs" 11602000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 003\CCC_ADE.cvs" 15938000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 003\DDD_AGA.cvs" 13556000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 003\EEE_ARR.cvs"  2152000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 003\D00_ARR.cvs"  2651000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 004\AAA_ACD.cvs"  4326000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 004\BBB_ADP.cvs" 13552000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 004\CCC_AFD.cvs"  7527000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 004\DDD_ADA.cvs"  5043000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 004\EEE_AXR.cvs"  2652000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 004\E00_AXR.cvs"  3552000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 001\Sub Dir 001\AAA_BCC.cvs"  4915000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 001\Sub Dir 001\BBB_BAA.cvs"  4621000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 001\Sub Dir 001\CCC_BFF.cvs" 15352000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 001\Sub Dir 001\DDD_BDD.cvs"  1902000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 001\Sub Dir 001\EEE_BYR.cvs"  4001000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 001\Sub Dir 001\F00_BYR.cvs" 11893000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 001\Sub Dir 002\AAA_BDD.cvs"  1778000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 001\Sub Dir 002\BBB_BPP.cvs" 10919000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 001\Sub Dir 002\CCC_BEE.cvs"  1031000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 001\Sub Dir 002\DDD_BDG.cvs" 18769000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 001\Sub Dir 002\EEE_BRY.cvs" 11401000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 001\Sub Dir 002\G00_BRY.cvs" 10582000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 001\Sub Dir 003\AAA_BAC.cvs" 11060000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 001\Sub Dir 003\BBB_BAP.cvs"  5780000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 001\Sub Dir 003\CCC_BDD.cvs"  2904000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 001\Sub Dir 003\DDD_BGD.cvs" 15582000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 001\Sub Dir 003\EEE_BYT.cvs" 17365000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 001\Sub Dir 004\H00_BAA.cvs"  4123000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 001\Sub Dir 004\AAA_BAA.cvs" 10044000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 001\Sub Dir 004\BBB_BDA.cvs"  1124000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 001\Sub Dir 004\CCC_BDD.cvs"  6117000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 001\Sub Dir 004\DDD_BGG.cvs" 16101000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 001\Sub Dir 004\EEE_BTT.cvs"  7312000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 001\Sub Dir 004\I00_BTT.cvs"  8271000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 002\Sub Dir 001\AAA_CXC.cvs"  1250000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 002\Sub Dir 001\J00_CXC.cvs"  2999000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 002\Sub Dir 001\BBB_CAA.cvs"  1264000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 002\Sub Dir 001\CCC_CFF.cvs"  5532000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 002\Sub Dir 001\DDD_CDD.cvs"  1198000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 002\Sub Dir 001\EEE_CYR.cvs"  3203000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 002\Sub Dir 001\K00_CYR.cvs"  3117000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 002\Sub Dir 002\AAA_CXD.cvs"  3008000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 002\Sub Dir 002\BBB_CPP.cvs" 10084000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 002\Sub Dir 002\CCC_CEE.cvs"  1005000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 002\Sub Dir 002\DDD_CDG.cvs"  8697000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 002\Sub Dir 002\EEE_CRY.cvs" 11099000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 002\Sub Dir 002\L00_CRY.cvs" 10310000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 002\Sub Dir 003\AAA_CAX.cvs"  9005000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 002\Sub Dir 003\BBB_CAP.cvs"  1178000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 002\Sub Dir 003\CCC_CDD.cvs"  3655000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 002\Sub Dir 003\DDD_CGD.cvs"  5530000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 002\Sub Dir 003\EEE_CYT.cvs"  2900000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 002\Sub Dir 003\M00_CYT.cvs"  2009000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 002\Sub Dir 004\AAA_CAX.cvs"  4101000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 002\Sub Dir 004\BBB_CDA.cvs"  2100000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 002\Sub Dir 004\CCC_CDD.cvs"  3600000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 002\Sub Dir 004\DDD_CGG.cvs" 15999000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 002\Sub Dir 004\EEE_CTT.cvs"  3123000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 002\Sub Dir 004\N00_CTT.cvs"  3923000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 003\Sub Dir 001\AAA_DAC.cvs"  1194000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 003\Sub Dir 001\BBB_DAA.cvs"  7017000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 003\Sub Dir 001\CCC_DXF.cvs"  8352000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 003\Sub Dir 001\DDD_DDD.cvs"  1199000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 003\Sub Dir 001\EEE_DXR.cvs"  4105000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 003\Sub Dir 001\O00_DXR.cvs"  2504000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 003\Sub Dir 002\AAA_DXD.cvs"  3558000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 003\Sub Dir 002\BBB_DXP.cvs" 12284000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 003\Sub Dir 002\CCC_DXE.cvs"  2811000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 003\Sub Dir 002\DDD_DXG.cvs"  1976000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 003\Sub Dir 002\EEE_DXY.cvs"  5132000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 003\Sub Dir 002\P00_DXY.cvs"  7801000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 003\Sub Dir 003\AAA_DXC.cvs"  2021000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 003\Sub Dir 003\BBB_DXP.cvs" 10209000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 003\Sub Dir 003\CCC_DXD.cvs"  2104000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 003\Sub Dir 003\DDD_DXD.cvs" 18584000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 003\Sub Dir 003\EEE_DXT.cvs" 50111000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 003\Sub Dir 003\Q00_DXT.cvs"  2150000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 003\Sub Dir 004\AAA_DXA.cvs" 14133000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 003\Sub Dir 004\BBB_DXA.cvs"  3284000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 003\Sub Dir 004\CCC_DDD.cvs"  8867000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 003\Sub Dir 004\DDD_DGG.cvs"  5911100
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 003\Sub Dir 004\EEE_DTT.cvs"  7130000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 003\Sub Dir 004\R00_DTT.cvs"  9991000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 004\Sub Dir 001\AAA_ECC.cvs"  1491000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 004\Sub Dir 001\BBB_EAA.cvs"  6209000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 004\Sub Dir 001\CCC_EFF.cvs" 11355000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 004\Sub Dir 001\DDD_EDD.cvs"  8911000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 004\Sub Dir 001\EEE_EYR.cvs"  1125000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 004\Sub Dir 001\S00_EYR.cvs"  1893000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 004\Sub Dir 002\AAA_EDD.cvs"  3778000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 004\Sub Dir 002\BBB_EPP.cvs" 10704000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 004\Sub Dir 002\CCC_EEE.cvs"  8254000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 004\Sub Dir 002\DDD_EDG.cvs" 11769000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 004\Sub Dir 002\EEE_ERY.cvs"  9997000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 004\Sub Dir 002\T00_ERY.cvs"  9814000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 004\Sub Dir 003\AAA_EAC.cvs" 13251000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 004\Sub Dir 003\BBB_EAP.cvs"  7811000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 004\Sub Dir 003\CCC_EDD.cvs" 12904000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 004\Sub Dir 003\DDD_EGD.cvs"  4312000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 004\Sub Dir 003\EEE_EYT.cvs"  8021000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 004\Sub Dir 003\U00_EYT.cvs" 10999000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 004\Sub Dir 004\AAA_EAA.cvs" 11150000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 004\Sub Dir 004\BBB_EDA.cvs"  2484000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 004\Sub Dir 004\CCC_EDD.cvs"  6167000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 004\Sub Dir 004\DDD_EGG.cvs" 15900000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 004\Sub Dir 004\EEE_ETT.cvs"  8540000
fsutil file createnew "X:\Root Dir\Dir 004\Sub Dir 004\V00_ETT.cvs"  7310000
```

The tree of created folders and files results in:

```bat
> Tree /F /A
Folder PATH listing
Volume serial number is 9A8E-862E
X:.
|   Create_Files.cmd
|   Q1672774.cmd
|   
\---Root Dir
    |   A00_ABC.cvs
    |   AAA_ABC.cvs
    |   BBB_ABC.cvs
    |   CCC_ABC.cvs
    |   DDD_ABC.cvs
    |   EEE_ABC.cvs
    |   
    +---Dir 001
    |   |   AAA_AAC.cvs
    |   |   B00_ART.cvs
    |   |   BBB_APD.cvs
    |   |   CCC_AED.cvs
    |   |   DDD_AAD.cvs
    |   |   EEE_ART.cvs
    |   |   
    |   +---Sub Dir 001
    |   |       AAA_BCC.cvs
    |   |       BBB_BAA.cvs
    |   |       CCC_BFF.cvs
    |   |       DDD_BDD.cvs
    |   |       EEE_BYR.cvs
    |   |       F00_BYR.cvs
    |   |       
    |   +---Sub Dir 002
    |   |       AAA_BDD.cvs
    |   |       BBB_BPP.cvs
    |   |       CCC_BEE.cvs
    |   |       DDD_BDG.cvs
    |   |       EEE_BRY.cvs
    |   |       G00_BRY.cvs
    |   |       
    |   +---Sub Dir 003
    |   |       AAA_BAC.cvs
    |   |       BBB_BAP.cvs
    |   |       CCC_BDD.cvs
    |   |       DDD_BGD.cvs
    |   |       EEE_BYT.cvs
    |   |       
    |   \---Sub Dir 004
    |           AAA_BAA.cvs
    |           BBB_BDA.cvs
    |           CCC_BDD.cvs
    |           DDD_BGG.cvs
    |           EEE_BTT.cvs
    |           H00_BAA.cvs
    |           I00_BTT.cvs
    |           
    +---Dir 002
    |   |   AAA_ADC.cvs
    |   |   BBB_AAD.cvs
    |   |   C00_AXT.cvs
    |   |   CCC_ADF.cvs
    |   |   DDD_AGD.cvs
    |   |   EEE_AXT.cvs
    |   |   
    |   +---Sub Dir 001
    |   |       AAA_CXC.cvs
    |   |       BBB_CAA.cvs
    |   |       CCC_CFF.cvs
    |   |       DDD_CDD.cvs
    |   |       EEE_CYR.cvs
    |   |       J00_CXC.cvs
    |   |       K00_CYR.cvs
    |   |       
    |   +---Sub Dir 002
    |   |       AAA_CXD.cvs
    |   |       BBB_CPP.cvs
    |   |       CCC_CEE.cvs
    |   |       DDD_CDG.cvs
    |   |       EEE_CRY.cvs
    |   |       L00_CRY.cvs
    |   |       
    |   +---Sub Dir 003
    |   |       AAA_CAX.cvs
    |   |       BBB_CAP.cvs
    |   |       CCC_CDD.cvs
    |   |       DDD_CGD.cvs
    |   |       EEE_CYT.cvs
    |   |       M00_CYT.cvs
    |   |       
    |   \---Sub Dir 004
    |           AAA_CAX.cvs
    |           BBB_CDA.cvs
    |           CCC_CDD.cvs
    |           DDD_CGG.cvs
    |           EEE_CTT.cvs
    |           N00_CTT.cvs
    |           
    +---Dir 003
    |   |   AAA_ADA.cvs
    |   |   BBB_AAP.cvs
    |   |   CCC_ADE.cvs
    |   |   D00_ARR.cvs
    |   |   DDD_AGA.cvs
    |   |   EEE_ARR.cvs
    |   |   
    |   +---Sub Dir 001
    |   |       AAA_DAC.cvs
    |   |       BBB_DAA.cvs
    |   |       CCC_DXF.cvs
    |   |       DDD_DDD.cvs
    |   |       EEE_DXR.cvs
    |   |       O00_DXR.cvs
    |   |       
    |   +---Sub Dir 002
    |   |       AAA_DXD.cvs
    |   |       BBB_DXP.cvs
    |   |       CCC_DXE.cvs
    |   |       DDD_DXG.cvs
    |   |       EEE_DXY.cvs
    |   |       P00_DXY.cvs
    |   |       
    |   +---Sub Dir 003
    |   |       AAA_DXC.cvs
    |   |       BBB_DXP.cvs
    |   |       CCC_DXD.cvs
    |   |       DDD_DXD.cvs
    |   |       EEE_DXT.cvs
    |   |       Q00_DXT.cvs
    |   |       
    |   \---Sub Dir 004
    |           AAA_DXA.cvs
    |           BBB_DXA.cvs
    |           CCC_DDD.cvs
    |           DDD_DGG.cvs
    |           EEE_DTT.cvs
    |           R00_DTT.cvs
    |           
    \---Dir 004
        |   AAA_ACD.cvs
        |   BBB_ADP.cvs
        |   CCC_AFD.cvs
        |   DDD_ADA.cvs
        |   E00_AXR.cvs
        |   EEE_AXR.cvs
        |   
        +---Sub Dir 001
        |       AAA_ECC.cvs
        |       BBB_EAA.cvs
        |       CCC_EFF.cvs
        |       DDD_EDD.cvs
        |       EEE_EYR.cvs
        |       S00_EYR.cvs
        |       
        +---Sub Dir 002
        |       AAA_EDD.cvs
        |       BBB_EPP.cvs
        |       CCC_EEE.cvs
        |       DDD_EDG.cvs
        |       EEE_ERY.cvs
        |       T00_ERY.cvs
        |       
        +---Sub Dir 003
        |       AAA_EAC.cvs
        |       BBB_EAP.cvs
        |       CCC_EDD.cvs
        |       DDD_EGD.cvs
        |       EEE_EYT.cvs
        |       U00_EYT.cvs
        |       
        \---Sub Dir 004
                AAA_EAA.cvs
                BBB_EDA.cvs
                CCC_EDD.cvs
                DDD_EGG.cvs
                EEE_ETT.cvs
                V00_ETT.cvs
```

---

## Check the results of the commands with the pre-set files as larger

The larger files are: `AAA_DXA BBB_ADP CCC_ADE DDD_BDG EEE_DXT`

Get and check on outputs in commands, the largest file as first item to be listed in outputs by groups (`AAA_??? - EEE_???`).

```bat
> for %G in (A,B,C,D,E)do @echo\File %G%G%G & @for /f tokens^=* %I in ('where /r . %G%G%G_*.cvs /t ^| sort /r')do @echo\%I
```

The `where` command used with `/t`, generates an output that starts the line by file size, and redirecting to `sort /R`, will reverse those lines from largest to smallest.

So the first line always contains the largest file regardless of whether it is in the current folder or subfolder.

```bat
File AAA
14133000    9/4/2021   10:51:41 AM  X:\Root Dir\Dir 003\Sub Dir 004\AAA_DXA.cvs
     ...
 1194000    9/4/2021   10:51:40 AM  X:\Root Dir\Dir 003\Sub Dir 001\AAA_DAC.cvs 

File BBB
13552000    9/4/2021   10:51:38 AM  X:\Root Dir\Dir 004\BBB_ADP.cvs 
     ...
 1124000    9/4/2021   10:51:39 AM  X:\Root Dir\Dir 001\Sub Dir 004\BBB_BDA.cvs

File CCC
15938000    9/4/2021   10:51:38 AM  X:\Root Dir\Dir 003\CCC_ADE.cvs
     ...
 1005000    9/4/2021   10:51:40 AM  X:\Root Dir\Dir 002\Sub Dir 002\CCC_CEE.cvs 

File DDD
18769000    9/4/2021   10:51:39 AM  X:\Root Dir\Dir 001\Sub Dir 002\DDD_BDG.cvs 
     ...
 1198000    9/4/2021   10:51:40 AM  X:\Root Dir\Dir 002\Sub Dir 001\DDD_CDD.cvs

File EEE
50111000    9/4/2021   10:51:41 AM  X:\Root Dir\Dir 003\Sub Dir 003\EEE_DXT.cvs
     ...
 1125000    9/4/2021   10:51:41 AM  X:\Root Dir\Dir 004\Sub Dir 001\EEE_EYR.cvs
```

---

## Apply the commands to delete the files keeping the largest files

Since in `for /F` loop it is possible to define an output number of the command you want to skip/ignore, so adding `skip=1`, this will results in actions within the loop for files smaller than the largest being one or more files, all will be reached.

```bat
for /f skip^=1^tokens^=1^,4* %I in (
    'where /r .\ String_*.cvs /t^|sort /r')do del /q /f /a: "%K"
```

The `Skip=1` also applies those files that do not meet their duplicity, and are ignored/skipped in loop: `A00_ABC.cvs - V00_ETT.cvs`.

**Obs.:** For cases where the size of the files is even being in different folders, `where /r .\ file.eXt /t |sort /r` results in the most recent will be listed first

Before executing a loop to delete, you can quantify each group and the total of files

```bat
> dir /b /s /a-d|findstr \\AAA_...\...|find /v /c ""
21
> dir /b /s /a-d|findstr \\BBB_...\...|find /v /c ""
21
> dir /b /s /a-d|findstr \\CCC_...\...|find /v /c ""
21
> dir /b /s /a-d|findstr \\DDD_...\...|find /v /c ""
21
> dir /b /s /a-d|findstr \\EEE_...\...|find /v /c ""
21
> dir /b /s /a-d|findstr \\[A-V][0][0]\_.*|find /v /c ""
22
> dir /b /s /a-d *_*.cvs|find /v /c ""
127

::      AAA_???.cvs = 21
::      BBB_???.cvs = 21
::      CCC_???.cvs = 21 
::      DDD_???.cvs = 21 
::      EEE_???.cvs = 21 
::   A-Z+00_???.cvs = 22  // single/unique files for test and kept //
::      ???_???.cvs = 127
```

Bat using loop to apply the listing of files in String_*.cvs groups and delete the smaller files so as to keep only the largest of each group and keep the files unique as well (no group if existing)

```bat
@echo off

cd/d "A:\Directory"||goto :eof 
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion 

for /f tokens^=* %%G in ('where /r .\ *_*.cvs /t'
    )do set "_n=%%~nG" & call %:^) "!_n!" "_!_n:*_=!"

%:^)
if not "%~1" == "" (set "_file=%~1" && (for /f skip^=1^tokens^=1^,4* %%I in (
    'where /r .\ !_file:%~2^=!_*.cvs /t^|sort /r')do del /q /f /a: "%%K") & exit /b 
    )else endlocal && goto :eOf
```

---

## Check if other files of the same extension and unique were kept

```bat
> for %G in (A,B,C,D,E)do @echo\File %G%G%G & @for /f tokens^=* %I in ('where /r . %G%G%G_*.cvs /t ^| sort /r')do @echo\%I

File AAA
14133000    9/4/2021   10:51:41 AM  X:\Root Dir\Dir 003\Sub Dir 004\AAA_DXA.cvs
File BBB
13552000    9/4/2021   10:51:38 AM  X:\Root Dir\Dir 004\BBB_ADP.cvs
File CCC
15938000    9/4/2021   10:51:38 AM  X:\Root Dir\Dir 003\CCC_ADE.cvs
File DDD
18769000    9/4/2021   10:51:39 AM  X:\Root Dir\Dir 001\Sub Dir 002\DDD_BDG.cvs
File EEE
50111000    9/4/2021   10:51:41 AM  X:\Root Dir\Dir 003\Sub Dir 003\EEE_DXT.cvs

> dir /b /s /a-d|findstr \\[A-V][0][0]\_.*|find /v /c ""
22
```

---

## Explaining what the bat is doing...

Go to your destination / root folder, if not there, abort the bat file without executing any command below/next:

```
cd/d "X:\Root Dir"||goto :eof
```

The `where` command in the loop will list the layout files in the name AnyString_AnyString.cvs recursively (`/r`).

```bat
for /f tokens^=* %%G in ('where /r .\ *_*.cvs /t'
    )do ...
```

The set is saving the name (without the extension "`%%~nG`") of the file and on the same line bat calls function (label `%:^)`) passing the name (`!_n!`) and strings before (and with) the underline in the name as an argument.

Ex: File in loop `AAA_XYZ.cvs`:

Argument 1 = `AAA_XYZ`
Argument 2 = `XYZ`

Ex: File in loop `%%~G`

Argument 1 = `!_n!`
Argument 2 = `_!_n:*_=!`

**Obs.:** The substring in `%2` argument is: `AAA_XYZ  == >  AAA_XYZ  == >  XYZ`

```bat
 ... set "_n=%%~nG" & call %:^) "!_n!" "_!_n:*_=!"
```

If any arguments are passed, use them inside the first `if(%1 == true)` condition otherwise, if no arguments are passed, end bat, there are no more looped files to be handled by the function, so go to the end of the file, ending

```bat
if not "%~1" == "" (do some in loop files) else (endlocal && goto :eOf)
```

Once the processing takes place within the function, define _file with the filename given in argument `%1`

```bat
set "_file=%~1" ... && (....
```

We will make use of the strings that are returned in the loop by the execution of where, in space-delimited form (default) in occurrences 1 and in all after the 4th (`4*`), skipping one (`skipˆ=1`), where the skipped item is our largest file (intentionally ignored)...

```bat
for /f skip^=1^tokens^=1^,4* %%I in (...
::      %%I    |--- Not In Use --| %%J                    %%K ==  *
::  1194000    9/4/2021   10:51:40  AM  X:\Full\Path\To\AAA_DAC.cvs 

::  %%I  size from file in loop 
::  %%J  just to have all strings after %%J in %%K 
::  %%K  all strings after %%J (including spaces if any)

::  %%I will be used as reference for sorting in sort /r 
::  %%J will not be used in any command
::  %%K will be used to delete the file passing the fullpath
```

Using a substring to remove the characters in the name after the "*", using the string passed by argument `%2` (in `!_file?;%2=!_*.cvs`), this will get the reference to find the relevant parity file via the recursive `where` inside the loop, Finding all AAA** files, using part of the name in the first file passed (`AAAA_*`), in the second (`BBB_*`), third, etc..

```bat
'where /r .\ !_file:%~2^=!_*.cvs /t^|sort /r'
```

Transforms the output in reverse form, sorting from largest to smallest, making use of the first characters of the line, (numbers corresponding to the file size).

```bat
'...^|sort /r')do ...
```

Loop `if (do (for () loop) & exit /b)` until the last file (smallest) if found and listed, and for each item found uses `%%k` (full path)  with `del` command to delete effectively.. and so when the loop ends, it exits the function and returns to where it was calling (the 1st loop in code that made the call (`call %:^) "!_n!" "_!_n:*_=!"`)..

```bat
.....(for ... (...)do del /q /f /a: "%%K") & exit /b
```

---

## Some further reading:

[√] **[If /?](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html)**

[√] **[Set /?](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html)**

[√] **[CMD /?](https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html)**

[√] **[For /?](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)**

[√] **[For /F](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)**

[√] **[Find /?](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)**

[√] **[Findstr /?](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)**

[√] **[Where /?](https://ss64.com/nt/where.html)**

[√] **[Where sample](https://www.petri.com/using-where-exe)**

[√] **[Redirection |, <, > 2>, ...](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php)**

[√] **[`Goto :Label` | `Call :Label`](https://ss64.com/nt/goto.html)**

[√] **[DelayedExpansion (Refer: `cmd /v /c`)](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)**

[√] **[`Set variable=variable:substrings` | DOS - String Manipulation](https://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php)**

**[How does the Windows Command Interpreter cmd.exe Parse Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/how-does-the-windows-command-interpreter-cmd-exe-parse-scripts)**

**[How-to: Escape Characters, Delimiters and Quotes at the Windows command line](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html)**